# Configuring If-else Statement in Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I'm trying to configure an if-else statement, but my code gets stuck on the if statement and doesn't go on to the else statement.

I've tried to add the `break;` to the if statement but it doesn't work, as well.

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('123/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2F')

WebUI.maximizeWindow()

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/input_ _Username'), 'admin')

WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/input_ _Password'), 'admin')

not_run: WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/span_Log in'), 1)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/span_Log in'))

not_run: WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/button_To activate session sta'), 1)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/button_To activate session sta'))

if (WebUI.verifyTextPresent("Operator already has active session", true)) {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('if-else/Page_Operator/button_Clear'))

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('if-else/Page_Operator/button_To activate session sta'))

    WebUI.waitForPageLoad(5)

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/click_phone'))

    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

    WebElement Table = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@id=\'missedCallsContainer\']'))

    List<WebElement> rows_table = Table.findElements(By.xpath('//tr[@class=\'dl-menu\']'))

    int rows_count = rows_table.size()

    println('No. of rows: ' + rows_count)
} 

else {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/click_phone'))
}
```

It works if the code goes in if statement but if that text that I have provided in if statement doesn't present, it stops working and doesn't go to else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is good, and I think you just need to change a bit at the if statement.
For if statement, I think you need to use another version of verifyTextPresent as below with one more parameter FailureHandling.OPTIONAL

[image]

More information can be found at https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/how_to_check_element_status_in_conditional_statement.html

Comment: Hello, i added FailureHandling.OPTIONAL and it actually helped me ad went to else statement, but the program says that there was a Warning making that test case and is it possible to avoid such situation ?

Comment: Is there any way to make it without FailureHandling ?

Comment: Warning is ok since it helps to know that the text is not present. If you do not want to use it, you could separated the verifyTextPresent out of if statement and use Try-Catch to catch the exception manually. Using FailureHandling is a good practice in Katalon Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation see driverfactory](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/using_selenium_webdriver_katalon_studio.html#driverfactory).

> Katalon developers were aware that WebDriver methods may be useful for users, so they introduced the DriverFactory library. This library is responsible for manipulation with the WebDriver instance and offers a few useful methods for using WebDriver in Katalon.
>
> One of the biggest benefits which are brought by this library is the changeWebDriver() method. As I mentioned earlier, it is not possible to use Katalon keywords with custom WebDriver instances by default. But as soon as you call this method, you’ll be able to use them. Katalon will set your driver as a default one, and the full Katalon’s functionality is provided.

Just add `DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)`:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('123/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2F')

WebUI.maximizeWindow()

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/input_ _Username'), 'admin')

WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/input_ _Password'), 'admin')

not_run: WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/span_Log in'), 1)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Log in/span_Log in'))

not_run: WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/button_To activate session sta'), 1)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/button_To activate session sta'))

if (WebUI.verifyTextPresent("Operator already has active session", true)) {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('if-else/Page_Operator/button_Clear'))

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('if-else/Page_Operator/button_To activate session sta'))

    WebUI.waitForPageLoad(5)

    WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/click_phone'))

    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    
    DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)

    WebElement Table = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@id=\'missedCallsContainer\']'))

    List<WebElement> rows_table = Table.findElements(By.xpath('//tr[@class=\'dl-menu\']'))

    int rows_count = rows_table.size()

    println('No. of rows: ' + rows_count)
} 

else {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('123/Page_Operator/click_phone'))
}
```